# Perl DBI:mysql connection over SSL fails

Tags: mysql, perl, ssl

Long time reader but this is my first question here.

I have a MySQL server in a data center and processing servers in another place, therefore I need to encrypt connections from my Perl scripts to the database. All the necessary settings were made on MySQL (creation of a new user, creation of ca, server and client keys) and MySQL connections over SSL work fine.

```
root@server:# mysql -h _HOST_ --port 3306 -u _SSL_USER_ --ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem -p _DATABASE_
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
Commands end with ; or \g. 
Your MySQL connection id is 49694205 
Server version: 5.0.96 Source distribution ...
```

So, I believe set up is good. The problem is that I can't make my Perl script to connect to the database. The returned error is simply:

Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'*HOST*' (using password: YES) at temp.pl line 7.

To simplify, I've put only the following code in my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use DBI; 

#DBI->trace(5); 
my $dbh = DBI->connect( 
  "DBI:mysql:database=_DATABASE_;host=_HOST_; 
  mysql_ssl=1; 
  mysql_ssl_client_key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem; 
  mysql_ssl_client_cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem; 
  mysql_ssl_ca_file=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem", 
  '_SSL_USER_', 
  '_SSL_USER_PWD_' 
) || die DBI->errstr; 
exit(0);
```

Perl version is v5.10.0 built for i486-linux-thread-multi.  The DBD::mysql module was compiled with the '-ssl' option.

I can't figure it out or find ways to further debug. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest version from all Perl modules?

I have found this thread: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,78084,78264#msg-78264

> Fixed it. Upgraded DBD-mysql from 2.9007 -> 3.0002 and it works like a
>   charm.

Maybe removing the username/password would help?

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( 
  "DBI:mysql:database=_DATABASE_;host=_HOST_; 
  mysql_ssl=1; 
  mysql_ssl_client_key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem; 
  mysql_ssl_client_cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem; 
  mysql_ssl_ca_file=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem", 
  '', 
  '' 
) || die DBI->errstr;
```

> Can't say what the problem is for you, but I'm assuming you have
>   included the username and password in the DBI->connect line and the
>   other thing is that the cacert and client certs need to be on your
>   remote computer (the one with the PERL script). Other than that I'd be
>   happy to help if you have more detail.

You could try to tracing the error: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#TRACING

```
DBI_TRACE=8=/tmp/dbitrace.log
export DBI_TRACE
./your_program.pl
```

You could use shell variables to make sure you are doing the same in Perl and in shell:

```
export DB_HOST="your host"
export DB_USER=""
export DB_PWD=""
export DB_DATABASE=""
mysql -h "$DB_HOST" --port 3306 -u "DB_USER" --ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem -p "$DB_DATABASE"

my $dbh = DBI->connect( 
  "DBI:mysql:database=$ENV{"DB_HOST"};host=$ENV{"DB_HOST"}; 
  mysql_ssl=1; 
  mysql_ssl_client_key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem; 
  mysql_ssl_client_cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem; 
  mysql_ssl_ca_file=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem", 
  '', 
  '' 
) || die DBI->errstr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm already running DBD-mysql-4.027 and removing the user/pass doesn't help, this information is required for user authentication.

Comment: Tested on Perl v5.14.2 with same results, unfortunately.  Any ideas on how to debug this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error message you have got? What is in the DBI trace log file?

Comment: I get a regular permission denied error, not sure how to further debug it:  "failed: Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'_DB_HOST_' (using password: YES)".  I don't how to enable DBI trace logs, can you help me with it?

Comment: Here is what the DBI trace log says:

Comment: '    DBI 1.631-ithread default trace level set to 0x0/1 (pid 2306 pi 8fd7008) at DBI.pm line 288 via temp.pl line 4
    -> DBI->connect(DBI:mysql:database=_DB_NAME_;host=_DB_HOST_;
                        mysql_ssl=1;
                        mysql_ssl_client_key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem;
                        mysql_ssl_client_cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem;
                        mysql_ssl_ca_file=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem, _SSL_USER_, ****)
    -> DBI->install_driver(mysql) for linux perl=5.010000 pid=2306 ruid=0 euid=0'

Comment: '       install_driver: DBD::mysql version 4.027 loaded from /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/i486-linux-thread-multi/DBD/mysql.pm
    <- install_driver= DBI::dr=HASH(0x916bcb8)
    !! The warn '0' was CLEARED by call to connect method
       ERROR: 1045 'Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'_SCRIPT_HOST_' (using password: YES)' (err#0)
    <- DESTROY(DBI::db=HASH(0x905f920))= undef at DBI.pm line 671
    !! ERROR: 1045 'Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'_SCRIPT_HOST_' (using password: YES)' (err#0)
    <- connect('database=_DB_NAME_;host=_DB_HOST_;
                        mysql_ssl=1;'

Comment: '                        mysql_ssl_client_key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem;
                        mysql_ssl_client_cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem;
                        mysql_ssl_ca_file=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem', '_SSL_USER_', ...)= undef at DBI.pm line 671
    <- $DBI::errstr= 'Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'_SCRIPT_HOST_' (using password: YES)'
       DBI connect('database=_DB_NAME_;host=_DB_HOST_;
                        mysql_ssl=1;
                        mysql_ssl_client_key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem;'

Comment: '                        mysql_ssl_client_cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem;
                        mysql_ssl_ca_file=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem','_SSL_USER_',...) failed: Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'_SCRIPT_HOST_' (using password: YES)
    <- $DBI::errstr= 'Access denied for user '_SSL_USER_'@'_SCRIPT_HOST_' (using password: YES)'
    !! The ERROR '1045' was CLEARED by call to disconnect_all method
    <- disconnect_all= (not implemented) at DBI.pm line 750
!   <- DESTROY(DBI::dr=HASH(0x916bcb8))= undef during global destruction'

Comment: The DBI trace shows "SSL_USER'@'SCRIPT_HOST" while in your command line example you are using "_SSL_USER_". In trace there is a SCRIPT_HOST while in your commandline example you are using _HOST_. Could it be a typo or you tried to edit the trace output?

Comment: The different "variables" are just caused by me removing sensitive information, I'm certain values are right in the script and command line tries.  Question is, how do I debug from here?  Did you guys have success using DBD:mysql over SSL?